# Syntax highlighting should be supported on Electrical Engineering, like on SO

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

I thought based on [this MSO question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting), it might be that syntax highlighting *is supported* here, as people rarely tag their questions with the appropriate language, so the highlighter might go into "null-mode" and do nothing.  However [this question of ours](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7815/problems-with-pic-a-d-conversion) seems to be a counterexample, which is tagged [c](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c) and not highlighted.

Based on the aforementioned MSO thread, I guess our entire site is blacklisted, which it should not be.  Also, it might be preferable to just live with auto-detected formatting on everything versus mandating software tags...but that's another question.  Conversely, I guess we could come up with our [own list](http://pastebin.com/AWMtu5rK) of `[arduino] = [lang-c]`, (...having trouble thinking of a common Java platform), etc.

The *vast* majority of code here is bound to be C, maybe some Java as well, which all should play nice with auto-detection.  ASM would fail hard, but assembly isn't (as far as we care here) standardized (a.k.a.: "wtf is an x86").

Comment: Since we have almost 2,000 questions now and not a single one requires Java highlighting (according to a quick search for 'java'), and also because you couldn't come up with a Java platform, I think it's not even worth mentioning.  C (and non-highlighting for assembly) is really all that's required.

Comment: Note, too, that we also have some HDL code: See [tag:verilog] and [tag:vhdl].  Verilog would probably be OK because it's C-like, but we'd want the [VHDL extension](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/src/lang-vhdl.js)

Answer (score 6):

This is now enabled.  There are 2 ways that it will kick in:

1. A moderator can set a language hint on a tag (on the tag info page)
2. It can be specified in the post with the code block by specifying a tag that has a hint per #1, or by specifying a [lang hint](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting):

```
<!-- language: lang-or-tag-here -->

    code goes here

<!-- language: lang-or-tag-here -->

    code goes here
```